# Find $AH$, where $H$ is the orthocenter of $\Delta ABC$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> In an acute-angled triangle $\Delta ABC$ , points $D,E,F$ are feet of the perpendiculars drawn from $A,B,C$ onto $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. Suppose $\sin A = \frac{3}{5}$ and $BC = 39$. Find $AH$, where $H$ is the orthocenter of $\Delta ABC$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

I am a bit weak at trigonometry, I had learnt the use of $\sin,\cos,\tan$ and all in right-angled triangles. Next I came to know that we have the Law of sines and cosines. The Law of sines tell us :-
$$\frac{\sin A}{BC} = \frac{\sin B}{AC} = \frac{\sin C}{AB} = \frac{3}{195}$$

From here, I don't know how to proceed. Some other ideas include that $H$ must be inside $\Delta ABC$, as the triangle is acute-angled. But is that intended?

Can anyone help? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/orthocentre-distance-to-triangle-vertices-as-a/).

Use formula $$AH = 2R \cos A = BC \cot A $$

> $$\cot A = \dfrac{4}{3} $$
>  $$ AH = 52$$

Summary of proof for $AH=2R\cos A$  in the link:

$BFCH$ as constructed is a parallelogram. Opposite sides are equal hence we have this formula.